# Error: failed to retrieve information about - when trying to install SpaTemplates

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

When I run this command

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

I get this error

```
Restoring packages for C:\Users\admin\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v1.0.4\scratch\restore.csproj...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.4\NuGet.targets(97,5): error : Failed to retrieve information about 
'Microsoft.NETCore.Targets' from remote source 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\packages\'. 
[C:\Users\admin\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v1.0.4\scratch\restore.csproj]
```

How should I resolve this and how is this even linked to service fabric?

Answer (score 4):

Find your local nuget.config with:

```
%appdata%/NuGet/NuGet.Config
```

And remove your local nuget package source.

I Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, you helped ME!   tyvm.